# cpu usage graph for specific method in the Time profile

Tags: xcode, instruments

I want to see the exact cpu usage graph in the Time profile in Instruments for a specific function getting called. How can i see that? can someone please guide me?

For example: Below in the time profiler cpu usage graph.

1. How can i know which line in the graph is specifically for a particular function called?
2. What are the core 0, core 1 is different from Time profiler cpu usage?
3. please refer bottom left portion of the screenshot..what does the second and weight column refers there?

[image]

Comment: Edit Question 3. It is hard to tell what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

> How can i know which line in the graph is specifically for a particular function called

By adding points of interest to your code (an OSLog feature). They, if you had any, would appear in the Points Of Interest graph; that's what it's for. Basically Instruments would *like* to answer this question, but you have to give it signposts to help it.

Comment: Ok thank you. I want to measure the performance of the application before adding and after adding a 3rd party sdk and initialization code in the main project.

Answer (score 1):

The Time Profiler instrument cannot do what you want it to do. It does not show how much CPU a function uses.

1. The graph in the Time Profiler instrument cannot show a particular function.
2. The Time Profiler graph shows the CPU usage of all the CPU cores combined. The Core 0 graph shows the CPU usage of Core 0. The Core 1 graph shows the CPU usage of Core 1.
3. The Weight column shows the amount of time the function is in the call stack. The Self Weight column measures the amount of time the function is at the top of the call stack. The Self Weight column is more important.

The following article provides more information on the Time Profiler instrument:

[Finding the Slow Spots in Your Code with the Time Profiler Instrument](https://www.swiftdevjournal.com/finding-the-slow-spots-in-your-code-with-the-time-profiler-instrument/)

Comment: Ok thank you. I want to measure the performance of the application before adding and after adding a 3rd party sdk and initialization code in the main project.